# Understanding multidimensional full covariance of normal multivariate distribution in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, normal-distribution

Suppose I have, say, 3 identically distributed random vectors: `w`, `v` and `x` generally with different lengths. `w` is length 2, `v` is length 3 and `x` is length 4.

How should I define the full covariance matrix `sigma` of these vectors for `tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(mean, sigma)`?

I think about full covariance in this case as [(2 + 3 + 4) x (2 + 3 + 4)] square matrix (tensor rank 2), where diagonal elements are standard deviations and non-diagonal are cross-covariances between each other component of each other vector. How can I switch my mind to the terms of multidimensional covariance? What is it?

Or should I build full covariance matrix by concatenating it from pieces (e.g. particular covariances and, for instance, assuming independence of these vectors I should build partitioned block diagonal matrix) and cut (split) results of sampling into particular vectors I want to get? (I did that with R.) Or is there an easier way?

What I want is full control over all random vectors including their covariances and cross-covariances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special consideration about the dimensionality just because your random variables are distributed across multiple vectors. From a probabilistic point of view, three normally-distributed vectors of sizes 2, 3 and 4, a normally-distributed vector of size 9 and and a normally-distributed matrix of size 3x3 are all the same: a 9-dimensional normal distribution. Of course, you could have three distributions of 2, 3 and 4 dimensions, but that's a different thing, it doesn't allow you to model correlations among variables of different vectors (just like having a one-dimensional normal distribution per number does not allow you to model any correlation at all); this may or may not be enough for your use case.

If you want to use a single distribution, you just need to establish a bijection between the domain of your problem (e.g. tuples of three vectors of sizes 2, 3 and 4) and the domain of the distribution (e.g. 9-dimensional vectors). In this case is pretty obvious, just flatten (if necessary) and concatenate the vectors to obtain a distribution sample and split a sample three parts of size 2, 3 and 4 to obtain the vectors.

Comment: If I would take 3 separate normal distributions to model these vectors, this won't guarantee zero cross-covariance between them, rigtht?

Comment: @konstunn It _does_ guarantee zero covariance, since having high or low values in one vector cannot possibly tell you anything about the others. In fact, having, for example, a multidimensional Gaussian distribution with a diagonal covariance matrix (sometimes called "ellipsoidal", or "spherical" if all the diagonal values are the same) is exactly the same as having multiple one-dimensional Gaussian distributions.